# Effect of Queue.poll()

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm trying to correct some of the bugs found by the FindBugs plugin in Eclipse in an outside project, and I'm getting following error:

> Method ignores return value

in this piece of code:

```
int maxSize;
Queue<e> queue;

(...)

while (queue.size() > maxSize) {
    queue.poll();
}
```

Unfortunatelly this is beyond my knowledge, and I would like to know what is the effect of the `poll()` method except returning `E` type object? Is it ok if I just removed this block of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `poll()` method will remove the object that is currently the head of the queue and return it as a result.

Removing `poll()` in the listed code will mean that the `while` loop will run endlessly, because you never change the queue length by removing elements from it.

The FindBugs warning means that you are calling a method, whose return type is not `void` and you are not assigning the result to another variable or using it in an expression. I would not modify the code, but rather try to suppress the warning using an annotation or ignore the warning as a whole.

Comment: It would be gazillion of error messages had FindBugs warn about every non-void method. How often do you check the result of `ArrayList.add` method?

Answer (score 2):

FindBugs maintains a database of methods which return type in general *must* be checked. The `Queue.poll()` method is [explicitly present](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/blob/f038694/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/ba/CheckReturnAnnotationDatabase.java#L126) in this database:

```
addMethodAnnotation("java.util.Queue", "poll", "()Ljava/lang/Object;", false,
            CheckReturnValueAnnotation.CHECK_RETURN_VALUE_LOW);
```

Note that the warning priority is assigned to LOW, so in this case FindBugs is not totally sure that you're doing the wrong thing.

While your code seems to be safe (at least for non-concurrent `Queue`), in general if you want to remove queue element and you are absolutely sure that the queue is non-empty, it's better to use `Queue.remove()`. In this case if something went wrong, you will get the `NoSuchElementException` instead of silently incorrect behavior. Bugs should manifest themselves.

So here you can either ignore this bug (with annotation or with xml exclude filters) or replace `poll()` with `remove()`.